# Is there a way to evaluate Android apps in a browser (like Pieceable for Android)?

Tags: applications

I have seen [Pieceable](https://www.pieceable.com/) which is a Website where you can upload iOS apps and then try them out directly in the browser. Is something like this also available for Android?

To upload an APK File, embed some code into a website and be able to try out the app before buying it?

Comment: No doing it as a developer. Uploading it as a developer to the website -> paid or not paid doesn't matter -> get code -> embedd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found [AppSurfer.com](http://appsurfer.com/) to work very nicely for me. They are still in BETA but in 1 - 2 months to come out with plans... It's free for 10 users at the same time at the moment and works quiet well...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for introducing Pieceable. After reading your question I learnt about it and when going beyond, I found [Amazon's Test Drive](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&docId=1000667581) seems to have a similar ability.  Thanks to @jcisio, I found this answer [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22396/how-does-amazon-test-drive-pieceable-viewer-work).  Currently the Amazon Test drive is available in US only. Hence, I could not test and verify it.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! Since I'm not located in the US I will have to wait a bit I guess... Thanks for your research!